# JavaFX DatePicker customization

Tags: javafx, datepicker, calendar, javafx-8

I'm using the `DatePicker` for the first time and I noticed something which I find highly irregular, at least from my point of view. In my case the first day of the week is Sunday. Here is how the calendar looks for May 2016 on the `DatePicker`.

[image: DatePicker Calendar]

And here is an example of what I would like , as the Windows calendar.

[image: Windows Calendar]

If the first day of the week is a 1st I'd like to display the last week of the previous month not the other way around. Is there any way to customize this? I have looked over the documentation and other issues with customization but haven't been able to find an answer.